# PHP-Composer, locally installed, remote installation need?

Tags: composer-php

This is a very simple question and I think that there will be someone who will mark me down for this, but I developed in PHP / CakePHP on my local Ubuntu system, and then install / ftp my code to my hosting company.

With CakePHP which is only PHP code, there is nothing to install, you have to set-up DB connections e.c.t but that is simple stuff but I have just come across PHP Composer, looks very easy to use and install locally.

My question is does it need to be re-installed on my hosting server, e.g once the code / php archive file is loaded into my project and its all working do I need to re-install it via SSH / curl, if so this might not be usable has I would not have access to my server to install it as root but it is only downloading code archive PHP file for use then would this work?

Sorry again for the newbe question but I can not seem to find a simple answer to my question.

Many Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you'll be able to run Composer locally and then ftp the result to the target server. This is the preferred setup, because otherwise you'd need a shell on the remote server, or some replacement, and that could mean less security, or it is even impossible with most shared hosting.

Comment: Does this require that the dev system is exactly the same as the server system? Same PHP version, same MySQL, same whatever ...

Comment: The PHP version should be reasonably "the same". Because you are not using any database when running Composer, it is irrelevant. Since PHP has greatly improved it's release process, breaking changes in patch versions are a thing of the past. However, the question of whether you can use a newer or older version in development (compared to production) entirely depends on whether your code triggers the bugs that have been fixed. This cannot be answered in general. Just be aware that some libs do require a certain patch version - dev and prod should both be able to use it in that case.